# How can I prevent loading my image slider until a user clicks a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I'm using this: http://galleria.io/ to create a popup image slider.
Basically I want it to appear fixed over my page only after the user clicks a link to open it (it will not open another page). If I use "display: none" it will load in the background slowing everything down as it will contain HD images.

Right now I am trying this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Testing</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="galleria/galleria-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .galleria {
      width: 700px;
      height: 400px;
      background: #000
    }
  </style>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>


  <a href="#" id="imageshow">Click me to load images</a>

  <script>
    function showGallery() {
      var content = "<div class=\'galleria\'><img data-src=\'photo1.jpg\'><img data-src=\'photo2.jpg\'><img data-src=\'photo3.jpg\'></div>";
      var hello = "hello world";
      console.log("hi it's working");
      $('body').append(hello);
    }

    $('#imageshow').click(function() {
      showGallery();
      Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
      Galleria.run('.galleria');
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**This the documentation for Galleria:**
http://galleria.io/docs/getting_started/beginners_guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a real good look at this and even downloaded the galleria.js for it. Coming to the simple conclusion that your code is likely to only miss a document ready statement :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    function showGallery() {
      var content = "<div class=\'galleria\'><img data-src=\'photo1.jpg\'><img data-src=\'photo2.jpg\'><img data-src=\'photo3.jpg\'></div>";
      var hello = "hello world";
      console.log("hi it's working");
      $('body').append(hello);
    }

    $('#imageshow').click(function() {
      showGallery();
      Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
      Galleria.run('.galleria');
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it did. Thanks for the follow up.

Comment: Cheers, same back at you. :-)